# Timing bash functions

Tags: bash, time, bash-function

I'd like to see how long it takes for a bash function to run. After doing a little research, I've come up with this approach which uses a sub-shell:

```
function test-function() {

    time (
        rsync -av ~/tmp/test-dir-start/  ~/tmp/test-dir-end/
        rsync -av ~/tmp/test-dir-start/  ~/tmp/test-dir-end-2/
        # etc...
    )

}
```

Are there alternate/better ways to time bash functions?

Update: I'm want the `time` call to be embedded in the function so that it runs every time without having to do `time test-function`. I should have been more clear on that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use command grouping rather than a subshell:

```
time { command1; command2; }
```

Update - more specific example:

```
test-function() {

  time {
     rsync -av ~/tmp/test-dir-start/  ~/tmp/test-dir-end/
     rsync -av ~/tmp/test-dir-start/  ~/tmp/test-dir-end-2/
     # etc...
    }
}
```